# How to download an ISO and directly create a bootable USB

Tags: curl, live-usb, iso, livecd, burning

How can I transfer an `.iso` file to an USB in parallel to the download of this file so that downloaded data gets directly on my USB  without passing through my hard drive.

Comment: For which reasons?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro [citation needed] ;-)

Comment: You're burning a USB stick?

Comment: bah, thought I read burning a DVD over an USB no idea why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wouldn't try it on a CD (although it might well be that my old buffering fears are outdated), but it works fine on a USB key; for example:

```
curl -L http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.6.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-8.6.0-amd64-netinst.iso | sudo dd of=/dev/sdf
```

downloads the current Debian network installer and writes it to the `sdf` key.

This works because `dd` reads by default from its standard input, if no `if` parameter is given. The `-L` parameter to `curl` tells it to follow redirections.

In fact there's no need to use `dd`; as `root`,

```
curl -L http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.6.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-8.6.0-amd64-netinst.iso > /dev/sdf
```

works fine too.

(Make sure you get the device right! You can easily destroy the wrong drive with this kind of command...)